# JavaScript exercise issue

Tags: javascript

i'm a novice in this world...so trying to begin, I started with an online tutorial. The exercise it's simple, but i can´t get the "empate" text on screen if the condition exists. Can you help me to know whats wrong?:

```js
var usuarioElige = prompt("piedra, papel o tijera?");
var computadoraElige = Math.random();
if (computadoraElige <= 0.34) {
    computadoraElige = "piedra";
} else if(computadoraElige <= 0.67) {
    computadoraElige = "papel";
} else {
    computadoraElige = "tijera";
}

var comparar = function (usuarioElige,computadoraElige) {
    if (usuarioElige === computadoraElige) {
        return "¡Es un empate!";
    }
};
```

Comment: Because the entered number never matches the generated random number?

Comment: You are not calling `comparar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the function that prints out the "enpate" message. Try this version:

```
var usuarioElige = prompt("piedra, papel o tijera?");
var computadoraElige;

var d = Math.random();
if (d <=0.34){
    computadoraElige = "piedra";
}else if(d <=0.67){
    computadoraElige = "papel";
}else{
    computadoraElige = "tijera";
}

var comparar = function (x,y){
    if (x===y){
        alert("¡Es un empate!");
    }
};

comparar(usuarioElige, computadoraElige)
```

Note the added call to the function at the end and that I renamed the parameters of the comparar function to "x" and "y" to avoid confusion (it also works if you stay with the old name).

Another thing is that I put the random number for the computer in a separate variable. It can be confusing if the same variable means two different things depending on what part of the program you are on.

I also improved the whitespace indentation of your program. Programs are easier to understand if they are well indented :)

Comment: it should be `if (x===y){`

Comment: Thanks!! it works. Now, what if i need to make another election in case of "empate"?

Comment: Use a while loop to repeat the election until you get a winner. The details I'll leave as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing:

```
comparar(usuarioElige, computadoraElige);
```

At the end of the code